# Integral $\int{\frac{(x-2)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Integral $$\int{\frac{(x-2)}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}}$$
I tried to insert under the differential but because of x-2 instead of x+2 that didn't help me totally.
We but $u =x^2+2x+10 $ and then $du = $ is $2x+2$, but we have $x-2$ so it doesn't help me anymore
 Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You break it into two parts : Note that $x-2 = \frac 12(x^2+2x+10)' -3$ (the $'$ is for derivative, which is $2x+2$), so
$$
\int \frac{x-2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}dx = \int \frac{(x^2+2x+10)'}{2\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}dx - \int \frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}dx
$$

The first follows from substituting $t = x^2+2x+10$ to get $\sqrt t$.

The second follows from $x^2+2x+10 = (x+1)^2 + 9 = (x+1)^2 + 3^2$, so :
$$
\int \frac{3}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}} = \int \frac{3}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+3^2}}
$$

Now remember the inverse hyperbolic sine derivative.

Note : a similar procedure may be followed for integration of $\frac{P(x)}{\sqrt{Q(x)}}$ for $P,Q$ of quadratic degree.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\int\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}\,\mathrm dx=\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}\,\mathrm dx-4\int\frac1{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+9}}\,\mathrm dx$

Comment: yep i have already checked this out but still can't understand how it can help
The first one is OK but the second one it's not even the perfect square

Comment: ah, I see :D
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

$\int\frac{x-2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}dx$ can be written as $$\int\frac{x+2}{\sqrt{x^2+2x+10}}dx-  4\int\frac1{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+9}} dx$$

The first one can be solved by substitution $u=x^2+2x+10$. And the second one, by substituting $v=x+1$.

$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u}} - 4\int \frac{dv}{\sqrt{v^2+9}}$$

$$=2\sqrt{u}-sinh^{-1} \frac{v}{3}+c$$

$$=2\sqrt{u}-\ln (v + \sqrt {{v^2} + {9}} ) + c$$

And if course, you will have to substitute back the functions $u$ and $v$.